# How to replicate iOS UIPickerView on web (HTML/JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, ios

I am trying to create the [UIPickerView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview) in my own Rails app through HTML and JavaScript, but the issue is that I can't use `select` or anything.

I want a similar effect to this, kind of like how the iOS Set Alarm page is. 
[image: Creating UIPickerView on web]

Do you have any input on how I can go about doing this?

Comment: any luck with that? i am working on similar thing

Comment: Well, initially, we ended up using `<select></ select>` menus, with tons of `<options>`. Then, we made it so the option tag, was always centred, etc, and we also hid the scroll bar using position absolute.

Comment: Shit son lol that’s bad

Comment: Yeah, we changed the design real quick